# how to add a second add to cart button on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a second add to cart button at the end of the page on my woocommerce product description. 
how do I do this?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Solution:** Add code in your theme's function.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="URL">Add to cart</a>';
}
```

**2. Solution:**  Install Custom WooCommerce Add to Cart plugin

[Custom WooCommerce Add to Cart Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-text-on-add-to-cart-button-for-woocommerce/)

**3. Solution:** You can use hooks with shortcodes:

[Custom add to cart button](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9)

Or create overrides for WooCommerce files in your own template.

Answer (score 13):

**Method-1**

```
$id = get_the_ID();
echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart id='.$id.']' );
```

**Method-2**

```
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
echo "<a href='".$product->add_to_cart_url()."'>add to cart</a>";
```

Would you please add above code end of the woocommerce product description?

---

**Method-3**

Add below code in your active theme `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_after_product_summary', 30 );

function custom_button_after_product_summary() {
  global $product;
  echo "<a href='".$product->add_to_cart_url()."'>add to cart</a>";
}
```

Comment: Could use a way to implement Method 1 - I need to add this code to the template and not sure how yet but do I need to add other code?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Add code in your active theme `functions.php.`

```
// Add "Add To Cart" button  //
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button2', 13 );
function add_a_custom_button2() {
    global $product;

    // Not for variable and grouped products that doesn't have an "add to cart" button
    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;

    // Output the custom button linked to the product
    echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <a class="customviewaddtocartbutton" href="' . esc_attr( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '">' . __('Add To Cart') . '</a>
    </div>';
}
```

**Styling:** Add Code in your `child-theme.css` or `theme.css`

```
/* Custom Add To Cart Button */
.customviewaddtocartbutton {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #E6723F !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 2px 2px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
}

.customviewaddtocartbutton:hover {
    background-color: #246e4c !important;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```