# What is functions.php Path in Wordpress WooCommerce Website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to add a new custom button next to **Add To Cart** button named **Add To Reserve List** on my WooCommerce Website.

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797697/how-to-add-a-second-add-to-cart-button-on-woocommerce) question, I need to find the path of `functions.php` file of my theme.

And currently, I'm using `emperor` theme and when I open up **`wp-content/themes/emperor/functions.php`** file, I get this content which seems to have uneditable content:

[image]

So now I wonder, what is the path of correct `functions.php` so that I can define my own function properly?

Comment: This is [ionCube](https://ioncube.com) encrypted file. So technically this is most likely the file you look for. I got no idea if said `functions.php` is part of WooCommerce or they encrypted it because they encrypted everything from the project. But if that is so you may try to replace it with version from vanilla distribution. But ionCube have mechanisms that can prevent this from working, so keep a backup or experiment on a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

Step1) First of all, go to the dashboard and click on "Appearance" (left side base) and check what is your currently active/running theme.

Step2) Open your wordpress site folder -> wp-content -> themes -> active/running theme -> functions.php

and write bellow your custom functions

Comment: But as you can see in the pic, there are some hashed encrypted data in this `functions.php` file! I don't where to add the code in this file ?

Comment: Ok, So you can create new files like custom-functions.php and write your custom function inside. and you can also include  custom-functions.php  file either functions.php or header/footer page or class controller page (if exist)